# asp.net development server port not same as web application port

Tags: asp.net, aspnet-development-server

When i run my asp.net web application on `VS2008 SP1`, it starts ASP.NET development server with port `1257` but web application is trying to be browsed on `localhost:1559`. So my web application can not be browsed by the explorer because the url is incorrect. I have to change the url manually on the explorer's address bar to browse web my application. You can guess this is a bit annoying. 
How can i resolve this issue? *(1257 and 1559 are just examples.)*

Answer (score -1):

I answer my own question incase someone needs the solution. 
The problem is about `ESET antivirus program` which i have. In ESET settings you need to go through "`settings/advanced settings/Web access security/Web browsers`". Then you will see a list of processes which ESET accept as a web browser. Uncheck the checkbox of "`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`" or "`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`". 
Then ESET will stop scanning your asp.net development server and your port number will match with the port number of opening browser page url.
You can also read this post: http://www.wahooga.com/2008/02/20/visual-studio-development-web-server-automatic-port-numbering-problem/